# Create CngKey from cert in localmachine store for use with ECDsaCng(CngKey)?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, signing, elliptic-curve, jwt

I have been trying to wrap my head around ECDsaCng, CngKey and signing with a valid EC cert. The cert is issued by "Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit Extended Validation CA", has a signature algorithm of "sha256ECDSA", a signature hash algorithm of "sha256", public key parameters = "ECDSA_P256" and key usage = "Digital Signature (80)".

Besides the ECDsaCng I have tried using JwtSecurityTokenHandler with the certificate, but I get a "certificate algorithm not supported" exception. Using a "standard" 2048-bit SSL cert with that Works fine.

What I need to do is sign a JWT with ES256, and so far this works only by using a "randomly generated" key of 256 bits with ECDsaCng, so an answer to any of these questions would really make my day:

1. How do I order a valid certificate that can be used with JwtSecurityTokenHandler for doing an ES256 signature?
2. How do I create a CngKey from my cert in the store? (The certificate's private key is not exportable.)
3. Is there any other way to sign with ES256 and a certificate private key that cannot be exported from store?

Pretty much any help is appreciated!

Best regards,

Henrik

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Yes and no. I had to use a locally generated private/public keypair. My working theory at the moment, is that an SSL certificate (of any kind) cannot be used for signing in Microsoft Cng, as this seems to enforce that certs should not have both the "Server Authenication" and "Code Signing" key usages. A cert for signing should ONLY have the "Code Signing" key usage.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.6.1 added significantly better support for doing ECDSA. In particular, the [GetECDsaPrivateKey (extension) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.ecdsacertificateextensions.getecdsaprivatekey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since the signing and verifying methods are on the ECDsa base class (as of .NET 4.6.1) you shouldn't really have need to work directly with the ECDsaCng type, unless you're trying to interact with named system keys or other direct system interop.